# sprite kit removing specific nodes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a game where a character runs forever to the right (the game is landscape). On the ground there are spikes that the character can jump over. Currently, I am creating a new (and somewhat random) set of spikes in almost a checkpoint-like style where once the character reaches a certain distance, the next set of randomly organized spikes are created and the checkpoint distance gets pushed back and so on. Along with the spikes, I have a separate but very similar checkpoint-like system that is used to create the tiles that make up the ground.
This is my code for that portion, 'endlessX' and 'endlessGroundX' are the checkpoint value:

```
- (void) didSimulatePhysics {
if (player.position.x > endlessX) {
    int random = player.position.x + self.frame.size.width;
    [self createSpike:random];
    endlessX += self.frame.size.width/2.2 + arc4random_uniform(30);
}
if (player.position.x + self.frame.size.width > endlessGroundX) {
    [self createGround:endlessGroundX];
    endlessGroundX += tile1.frame.size.width;
}
    [self centerOnNode: player];
 }
```

The parameter of the createSpike and createGround method is just the 'x' value for the SKSpriteNodes.
I am currently having it as the character itself is the one moving and the spikes and tiles are stationary. This is how I am creating the character:

```
-(void) createPlayer {

player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"base"];
player.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
player.name = @"player";
player.zPosition = 60;
player.xScale = 0.8;
player.yScale = 0.8;
player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:player.frame.size.height/2];
player.physicsBody.mass = 1;
player.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
player.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
player.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
player.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(400, 0);
player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory;
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory | spikeCategory;
[myWorld addChild:player];
  }
```

With that, the character will never lose any of its kinetic energy to friction or any other force like that. Then, I am using the 'center on node' method that apple used in their adventure game so that the character will always remain in the same x-position on the screen:

```
- (void) centerOnNode: (SKSpriteNode *) node {
CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
node.parent.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/5 + node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, node.parent.position.y);
  }
```

I am calling this method in 'didSimulatePhysics.'

```
When I run this for some time, the programs gets slower and slower. I am guessing that that is due to the fact that I am never removing these nodes and they are always being added. However, to fix this problem, I tried doing something like this:

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.x + 50 < player.position.x) {
        [node removeFromParent];
    }
}];  
}
```

(the +50 would be just to make sure that the node is off the screen before removing it)
However, when I did this, instead of removing the specific node that satisfies the 'if' statement, the program removes all of the sprite nodes. Is there a different method or something that I am missing to fix this? Or are there any other simple ways to remove the specific nodes?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? How about you set a breakpoint inside that if statement block and verify the values are what you 'expect' them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking quite a few details, like how you are animating the spikes for instance, makes it a bit hard to be too specific. Nevertheless, from what you are sharing I guess you might be looking for something a little like this:

```
    SKAction *moveSpikeAction = [SKAction moveToX:-50 duration:5];
    SKAction *removeSpikeAction = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *spikeSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveSpikeAction, removeSpikeAction]];
    [yourSpikeSpriteNode runAction:spikeSequence];
```

The idea simply being that when the spike has animated to the off screen position you use the `removeFromParent` action to clear it.

Comment: I just edited my post. Sorry, I did not even think about doing it the way you just described. At the moment, I am actually having the character move and the spikes and tiles remain stationary. Is there any way to fix the problem in the format that I have it? Or would it be simpler to remove the center on node method and just switch over to the way you described?

Comment: I'd say that pretty much depends on the project. If your game is an endless runner constantly moving on one axis, yes then I believe what I describe is the easiest way to go. If you're creating something a bit more complex with movement in several directions and the user controlling the speed, then you should probably find a better solution...

Comment: I am trying to make it constantly on the x-axis so I'll switch over to that way! However, how would you be able to continuously create these spikes as the person plays?

Comment: You could just have a timer adding new spikes at whatever interval you decide.